# Ramification of primes without knowing the discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{5}] \ $, and let $\mathbb{L}$ be the normal closure of $\mathbb{K}$.

Let $\mathbb{O}_{\mathbb{K}} \ $ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$ and $\mathbb{O}_{\mathbb{L}} \ $ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{L}$. I want to find the factorization of the primes $7, 11 \ $ and $13$ as ideals in $\mathbb{O}_{\mathbb{K}} \ $ and $\mathbb{O}_{\mathbb{L}} \ $. My question is : how can I do that without knowing an integral basis for $\mathbb{K}$ and $\mathbb{L}$ ?

Comment: @Servaes So you get which primes ramify, but what about how a prime in general factors?

Comment: I think that it’s $\mathbb K$ that’s $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3-5)$, since the dimension is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to work on such things on a fairly mindless and *ad hoc* basis. Let me show you my approach just for the case $p=7$:

The extension $\mathbb K\supset\mathbb Q$ is of degree $3$, and in the downstairs residue field $\mathbb F_7$, $5$ is a generator of the multiplicative group so that $\lambda=5^{1/3}$ has period $18$. You need to go all the way to $\mathbb F_{243}$ to get $18|(7^n-1)$, so that the residue-field extension degree is three, and the prime $7$ does not split at all in $\mathbb K$. On the other hand, we have $(\frac{-3}7)=(\frac47)=1$, so that in $\mathbb Q(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity, $7$ should split, indeed $7=(2-\omega)(2-\omega^2)$. So there are at least two primes above $7$ in $\mathbb L$, but we know that each of these has residue-field extension degree $3$. So there you are, you can now try the same kind of argument at $11$ and $13$.

Answer (score 2):

For a prime $p$ in $\mathbb Z$ unramified in an extension $K=\mathbb Q(\beta)$, if we are merely *close* to the true ring of algebraic integers, meaning that $p$ does not divide the discriminate of $\mathbb Z[\beta]$, then the *localization* at $p$ of the true ring of integers is the same as the localization of this good approximation. Thus, looking how the minimal polynomial for $\beta$ factors mod $p$ will show how $p$ splits.

Comment: I mean, in theory, we can get away with this in general. Namely, for any $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ there is a primitive element $\theta$ for $K/\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $p$ is relatively prime to the conductor of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ which allows you to factor $p\mathcal{O}_K$ via the factorization of $m_\theta$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. But, this is quite a lot of work, no? :) I would imagine in most cases, it's probably easier to just find an integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, in many examples the "obvious" guess for something merely _close_ to generator for the ring of integers succeeds for all primes not "obviously" involved in either the degree of the extension or in whatever "root-taking" the extension involves. Of course, further tricks exploiting the cyclic-ness of extensions of finite fields reduces workload further in seeing how the minimal polynomial factors mod $p$. No trivial general human-executable approach, I think.

Comment: This is really a local question, and a global critter like a $\mathbb Z$-basis for the (global) integers is just not necessary.

Comment: @Lubin Although definitely effective for the reasons both I and Paul Garret said. If you choose a generic primitive element $\theta$ in the ring of integers, there are only finitely many primes aren't amenable to the Dedekind-Kummer theorem WRT the order $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$, right?

Comment: @Alex Youcis, as I said, I tend to look at these things in a very *ad hoc* way, and in this case, you just look at the situation and see that the only possible ramification is at $3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 1):

A usual method is to look at $f=x^3-5$ in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ ($p$ the prime you want to factorize). If $f$ has no multiple factors then the factorization of $f$ gives you the factorization of $p$; $p$ is unramified. Namely, $f=f_1f_2...f_k$ means $p=P_1P_2...P_k$, the norm of $P_i$ is $p$ to the degree of $f_i$, and $P_i=(p,f_i(\alpha))$ ($\alpha=\sqrt[3]{5}$).This is the case for all $p$'s you consider, as $f'=3x^2$.

As an example, for $p=7$, $x^3-5$ has no root in $\mathbb F_7[x]$ (if I didn't miss it), i.e. $(p)$ stays a prime ideal on $O_K$.

Should it fail (i.e. should $f$ have multiple factors in $\mathbb F_p[x]$), one can always look at the factorization of $f$ in $\mathbb Q_p[x]$ + some (not so small) details.

Comment: but this is valid only if the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ in $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[\beta]$ for some $\beta \in \mathbb{K}$

Comment: @boris I supposed $f$ has no multiple factors in $\mathbb F_p[x]$, so no further assumptions are needed